# alter table add column not always propagating in cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am using apache cassandra (v. 2.0.9) on a 4-node cluster, replication factor = 3 and Datastax Java Driver for Cassandra (v. 2.0.2). I am using CQL queries from inside my Java code to add columns to existing tables.

I observed this issue when my CREATE INDEX queries and SELECT queries on the newly added columns failed, reason being that the column was not found. No error was logged in cassandra logs.

Note that this issue did not appear when I ran cassandra on a single node, but occurs persistently on 4-node cluster. Currently I am working around it by retrying for at most 5 times and I notice that columns are added at most by third or fourth retry. Also I observed that higher the number of existing columns in a table, lesser are such failures.

I found a bug already reported at:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7186

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine after I disabled all firewalls, so this may be happening due to cassandra using particular ports for communication between nodes & that being blocked due to firewall.